# SoapUI Java Library Resource Leak

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, soapui, webservice-client

I've built a small standalone application that will output all of the operations specified in a WSDL file.  To do this, I'm using the SoapUI v5.1.3 library and am running the app on Java 8.

What I observed is that the application never exits and the java.exe process continues running in the background.  I stripped the program to barebones and found that the instantiation of the WsdlProject class appears to be the culprit.  If I remove the construction of the object, the program exits as expected.

```
public class WsdlUtilities {
    public static void main(String[] argvs) {
        WsdlUtilities utils = new WsdlUtilities();
        utils.printOperations();
    }

    public void printOperations() {
        WsdlProject project = null;

        try {
            project = new WsdlProject();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (project != null) {
                project.release();
            }             
        }
    }
}
```

As you can tell, I've attempted to call the release method on the WsdlProject object in the hope that all resources would be released.  That also did not work.

Am I missing something in terms of a method call that I need to make once I'm done with the WsdlProject object?

The JavaDocs don't give much detailed information, and I don't see any kind of closing or release information detailed on the SoapUI page (https://www.soapui.org/developers-corner/integrating-with-soapui.html#_ga=2.102243457.1272842168.1551742509-1552392744.1551742509).

Comment: Just for the heck of it : Have you tried to do a System.exit(0) as your last line of code? Just in an attempt to pull everything on the floor. Careful though. I think it will even kill your SoapUI, so it literally should be your very last line of code to execute.

Comment: @Steen I actually did try that, and it does work.  However, this is not acceptable to me.  I attempted to incorporate this into the web app that I'm working on, and I noticed that memory usage spiked each time the functionality was utilized.  It seems there is no way to release the handle on the resources that the WsdlProject object possesses.  I'm likely going to abandon the use of this library.